# Milestone information overlapping other text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

Is this new feature or bug? I did clear the browser's cache and login again. I am still seeing the issue, milestone icon is overwritten.

[image: Milestone icon and text is sitting on top of the information for progress toward the next privilege which is also sitting on top of the reputation chart.]

Comment: repro-ed in Chrome, FF and Edge, all on Win10

Comment: ah I was also searching for bugs :p ... they made some updates so for sure this will happen. I couldn't find this one since I have all the privilege :/

Comment: I'm also able to reproduce in Chrome 67.0.3396.99 with MacOS 10.13.4.

Comment: Clarification: I don't have a milestone, the text for the next privilege is doing the same thing (which is also visible in your screenshot).

Comment: Yup. This is a bug. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313434/ugly-next-privilege-text-on-user-activity-page

Comment: Repro-ed on Opera 55.0.2994.23 on Win10

Comment: A-HA it seems internet explorer has won this fight http://prntscr.com/kd9xm7 (if you cant open the image, its similar but the privilege doesn't overlap where it says next privilege)

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Probably just because there is less text on your next privilege than the one in OPs screenshot. I see exactly the same in Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i8C7.png

Comment: @Scoots shh don't take this win away from IE

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome 67, Vivaldi 1.15, and IE11, all on Win7/x64

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. We recently updated our progress bar styles and the privilege progress bar styles weren't correctly updated. This has been corrected now.

[image]