# Privilege tracking change - intended?

Tags: bug

I was just watching my own profile's [activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4569506/daniel?tab=topactivity) when I noticed the privilege tracking has changed and now looks quite odd (it's difficult to see your progression because the green bar is hid behind the name of the next privilege).

It must be a very recent change, because I'm certain it wasn't like that earlier today.

Is this intentional?

[image]

Comment: Related: [Milestone information overlapping other text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371818/2675154)